# Why does this zz plant have white residue and holes?

Tags: mildew, zzplant

My ZZ plant has developed a thin white residue and holes on some of the leaves.

We have had the ZZ plant about a month where it sits in a corner of the bedroom by a window. We have watered it once in that time.

What might be the problem? And how do we fix it?

My suspicion is powdery mildew, but I am not sure.

[image: Plant]

Comment: I see fluffy white deposits on top of the soil in a couple of places too, though it may not be significant... please check carefully beneath the leaves and on stems for anything that shouldn't be there, like faint webbing traces or small insects. Does the pot it's in have drainage holes and if its sitting inside an outer pot, does it reach to the bottom of the outer pot? Is there any standing water sitting inside the outer pot?

Answer (score 2):

The two holes that I see appear to be from slugs feeding on the leaf and seem to be quite old, while the white staining on the leaves is probably residue from the place where the plant was purchased watering the plant from overhead with a water-fertilizer solution. It could also be from overhead watering with hard water. I see no evidence of mealybugs or spider mites. Wipe the leaves with a damp cloth and the white staining should disappear or fade.